# Tiles-el get spring security principal object

Tags: spring-security, tiles2

I have project running spring with tiles2 and Thymeleaf template engine.
In tiles I want to display an authentication navbar depending if the user is authenticated or not, to do so I'm using apache-tiles EL to choose which navbar will be selected.
here is my tiles definition

```
`<definition name="abstract.layout" template="/layouts/abstractLayout" templateType="thymeleaf" >
    <put-attribute name="navbar" type="definition" expression="${principal} !=null ? 'authenticated.navbar' : 'guest.navbar'" />

    <put-attribute name="title" value="company" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="description" value="E-Commerce Platform" type="string" />
    <put-attribute name="sidebar" value="/layouts/fragments/sidebar/sidebar::content" type="thymeleaf"  />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/layouts/fragments/footer::content" type="thymeleaf" />

    <put-list-attribute name="thirdPartyCssFiles" >
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="customCssFiles">
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="pluginJsFiles">
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="customJsFiles">
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>`
```

When I'm evaluating the tile, the variable ${principal} isn't found in the evaluation context.

My questions are:

- How to get the spring-security principal object and how to know if the user is authenticated?
- Is there a way to use SPEL instead of EL or ONGL in expressions?

Thank you